# Android png performance

Tags: android, image, performance

I have asked similar questions a few times and still have not resolved my issue, so I thought I'd come at it another way and see if anyone can help me out.

I am writing a game for Android; this is my first attempt at a program this large/complex. The game is a 2d action/puzzler, and I am using Canvas rather than OpenGL ES for drawing.

Everything is going well, except when I try to draw pngs/bmps/jpgs, any images I imported myself. I can draw shapes and animations using the built-in Android canvas drawShape methods (including many Paints with Alpha content) till the cows come home, and maintain over 60fps, but as soon as I try to add my own image (say, a 60kb png saved from Photoshop) I immediately see a major performance hit. The bigger the size of the png on the screen, the bigger the hit (which makes sense).

I have a simple question that may help me understand if I'm doing something wrong here:

If you use the Canvas draw method to draw a red rectangle on the screen, should I expect it to be possible to instead import and display a red rectangle of the same dimensions without a loss in performance? I have done a lot of research on this issue but it is still not clear to me why Android (or Nexus 7) would have such a hard time with my images.

Is Canvas the problem? Do I need to port to Libdgx or AndEngine (that will be a process I think...)?

If it helps, this is how I'm loading my assets:

```
@Override
public Image newImage(String fileName, ImageFormat format) {
    Config config = null;
    if (format == ImageFormat.RGB565)
        config = Config.RGB_565;
    else if (format == ImageFormat.ARGB4444)
        config = Config.ARGB_4444;
    else
        config = Config.ARGB_8888;

    Options options = new Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = config;     

    InputStream in = null;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    try {
        in = assets.open(fileName);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
        if (bitmap == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load bitmap from asset '"
                    + fileName + "'");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load bitmap from asset '"
                + fileName + "'");
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }   

    if (bitmap.getConfig() == Config.RGB_565)
        format = ImageFormat.RGB565;
    else if (bitmap.getConfig() == Config.ARGB_4444)
        format = ImageFormat.ARGB4444;
    else
        format = ImageFormat.ARGB8888;

    return new AndroidImage(bitmap, format);
}
```

Comment: I'm using LibGdx for my Game. The performance is never hit even when I'm using large image files..

Comment: Can you show the code where you are drawing the image on the canvas?

Comment: how you have increased the fps? please can u share some code

Answer (score -1):

Canvas are slower than GLSurfaceView, but on Nexus 7 should handle 300 bitmap on one screen with no sweat.

Search your performence problem in onDraw.
Watch this for tips and tricks in real time game design:
http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/writing-real-time-games-android.html

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link. Imagine that page is moved to another server, or the direct link changes - future users will not be able to benefit from the answer. Take a look at [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).